# Initialize variable by evaluating lambda directly

Tags: java, lambda

I am wondering if there is a way to call `.apply()` or `.get()` on a lambda function directly in the same expression it is defined. The question came to mind when I wanted to initialize a variable which could be private, but I cannot declare it final because the value is the return value of a function that can throw an exception. As an example, consider `Files.size(path)`:

```
 final s = Files.size(path);
 // code that uses s
```

Now, if I want to use a default value for `s` if there is an exception, I have to add a `try/catch`, but this is a statement and not an expression:

```
s = 0;
try {
    s = Files.size();
}
catch (IOException e) {}

 // code that uses s
```

The obvious solution is to just declare a small helper function that wraps the try/catch, e.g. `getFileSizeOrZero`. I could also write a generic function that wraps this as a general case. This is nice and descriptive, but a more local function approach whould be better.

In C++, I used lambdas:

```
const s = []() {
    try {
        return Files.size(path);
    } catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}();
```

so I wondering if this can be done in Java. The best I could come up with was

```
final int s = new IntSupplier() {
    @Override
    public int getAsInt() {
        try {
            return Files.size(path);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
 }.getAsInt();
```

This seems to be quite expressive, so I am hoping that there is some syntac that I don't know enabling

```
final int s = () -> {
    try {
        return Files.size(path);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}.apply();
```

It seems that the problem is there is no function call operator as in C++, so there has to be a named member function which can be called.

Comment: " I cannot declare it final because the value is the return value of a function that can throw an exception" Why does this stop you making it final?

Comment: @AndyTurner Maybe I misformulated it a bit. It doesn't stop me, but then I have to put the variable inside the scope of the try statement, so I effectively have to put all code that uses it into the try statement.

Comment: "The obvious solution is to just declare a small helper function that wraps the try/catch, e.g. getFileSizeOrZero. I could also write a generic function that wraps this as a general case. This is nice and descriptive, but a more local function approach whould be better." - Why would it be better?

Comment: I don't like to create functions which are used this very specific local reason in an outer scope. It just pollutes the class. It is not very bad as they are private functions, but I just would like to keep things local.

Comment: @AndyTurner You proposed a solution `    private void foo(Path p) {
        final long s;
        try {
            s = Files.size(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            s = 0;
        }
    }` which does not compile with an error "variable s might already have been assigned". Do you know why the compiler rejects this? From what I see, there is always exactly one path which initialized `s`, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Jens it's because of the definite assignment rules in [JLS Sec 16.2.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.15), specifically "V is definitely unassigned before a catch block iff all of the following are true: V is definitely unassigned after the try block. ...". That first condition isn't met, so it's not definitely unassigned in the catch.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. I always thought that this was defined in terms of program paths. It's kind of an unintuitive approximation of paths by blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this but you need to explicitly cast the anonymous lambda to the correct type. That's because you need to coerce the type of the lambda to the specific functional interface, Java can't guess the final type, eg:

```
final int x = ((IntSupplier)() -> 5).getAsInt();
```

If you don't like it you need to store it in a variable:

```
final IntSupplier xx = () -> 5;
final int x = xx.getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot declare it final because the value is the return value of a function that can throw an exception

Why does this stop you making it final? Just declare the variable outside a try/catch.

```
final long s;
{
  long ss;
  try {
    ss = Files.size(path);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    ss = 0;
  }
  s = ss;
}
```

---

Note that you can't simply use `s` in place of `ss` int the try/catch, because of the rules of definite assignment, [specifically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.15):

> V is definitely unassigned before a catch block iff all of the following are true:
>
> - V is definitely unassigned after the try block.
> - ...

That first condition is not true, so the rest are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

One of your problems is that `Files.size(path)` actually returns a `long`, so you need to assign it to one.

That allows you to do:

```
    long size = ((LongSupplier) () -> {
        try
        {
            return Files.size(path);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }).getAsLong();
```

So you only have to cast the lambda and have a single logical line expression.

I would also say a general function should be in order

```
public long defaultOnException(LongSupplier s, long defaultValue) {
    try { 
        return s.getAsLong(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

which would make your client code

```
long size = defaultOnException(() -> Files.size(path), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the alternative:

```
    final int s = (IntSupplier) () -> {
        try {
            return Files.size(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }.getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using generics:

```
    final long size = ((Supplier<Long>)(() -> {
        try {
            return Files.size(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0L;
        }
    })).get();
```